# Django's analog of SQL "INNER DJOIN"

Tags: python, sql, django

```
#models.py
#
class Students(models.Model):
    StudentID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    FIO = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    StudGroup = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    NYear = models.IntegerField()

class Phone(models.Model):
    Code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    StudentID = models.ForeignKey(Students)
    Phone = models.BigIntegerField()


#views.py
#
def show_all(reqest):
all_students = Students.objects.all()
return render_to_response('demosite/index.html', 
        {'All_students': all_students})
```

This code is working normally.

Now my view returning this request:

```
SELECT * FROM Students
```

But variable all_students should contain data from 2 tables.

How do i get django to run this request:

```
SELECT Students.FIO, Phone.Phone FROM Students INNER DJOIN Phone ON Students.StudentID = Phone.StudentID
```

Comment: When you work with the Django ORM stop thinking in SQL. In your case you can access the phone records of a student via the reverse relation of the ForeignKey. The default name should be `phone_set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Student FIO and Phone.Phone of students,

You could do something like this,

```
Phone.objects.values('Phone', 'StudentID__FIO')
```